# Y/N Prompt For Reboot in Batch File

Tags: batch-file, cmd, prompt, reboot

I have to provide a batch file for about 1000 workstations to edit a few registry keys and reboot the machine.  I've got everything worked out with the registry keys, but I want to give a Y/N prompt for the reboot.  So far I have:

```
@echo off
setlocal
:PROMPT
SET /P AREYOUSURE=To continue, the workstation must reboot.  Would you like to reboot now (Y/[N])?
IF /I "%AREYOUSURE%" NEQ "Y" GOTO END

echo ... rest of file ...

:END
endlocal

shutdown.exe /r /t 00
```

This is my first attempt at this, and it seems to reboot no matter what is pressed.  Any pointers on what I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: If you're wanting to not shutdown if the user chooses *N*, then your `shutdown` needs to be before `:end`, not after it.

Comment: I'd use `choice.exe /?` to have a yes/no question answered and have a default answer maybe with a timeout.

Comment: This `SET /P AREYOUSURE=To continue, the workstation must reboot.  Would you like to reboot now (Y/[N])?` should be `SET /P AREYOUSURE=To continue, the workstation must reboot.  Would you like to reboot now (Y/[N])?:`

Comment: Using `Choice` its a two liner: `@Choice /M "Would you like to reboot now"`, `@If "%ErrorLevel%"=="1" Shutdown /R /T 0 /D P:0:0`.

Comment: Ken White, that makes too much sense, and works very well!  Thank you!

Comment: Adding to Ken White's advisory, why bothering to use labels and gotos when you can directly call shutdown with satisfied IF condition? `IF /I "%AREYOUSURE%"=="Y" shutdown.exe /r /t 00`. And I would suggest you to enable delayed expansion and use `IF /I "!AREYOUSURE!" ...` instead. because user can enter anything in the prompt and disrupt the batch parser. with delayed expansion you can prevent that to happen, or better than that, use `choice.exe` as advised by LotPings and Compo

Answer (score 1):

This works -

```
    @ECHO Off
    SET /P yesno=Do you want to Reboot this machine? [Y/N]:
    IF "%yesno%"=="y" GOTO Confirmation
    IF "%yesno%"=="Y" GOTO Confirmation
    IF "%yesno%"=="n" GOTO End
    IF "%yesno%"=="N" GOTO End
    
    :Confirmation
    
    ECHO System is going to Reboot now
    
    shutdown.exe /r 
    
    GOTO EOF
    :End
    
    ECHO System Reboot cancelled
    
    TIMEOUT 5 >nul
    
    :EOF
    exit
```